# SQL connection busy although it's already closed

Tags: java, sqlite, runtime-error

My SQL connection keeps saying it's busy even though all previous connections are closed.
The error below results. All others are either closed by the exiting of the JFrame or the .close() method. Does anyone see anything wrong with the class? (All other classes work as intended.)

```
SEVERE: null
org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_BUSY]  The database file is locked (database is locked)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:941)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:953)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.execute(DB.java:854)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.executeUpdate(DB.java:895)
```

```
package teacherreviewproject;
//initialise imports
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class FeedbackForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {
//init. variables
    String WWW;
    String EBI;
    int rating;
    String teacher;
    String studentUser;
    String ratingraw;
    String teacherQuery;
        
    public FeedbackForm(String s) {
        
        initComponents();
        getTeachersNames();
        this.studentUser = s;
    }
    
    private void getTeachersNames(){
        
     //get the connection
        Connection con = DBConnection.getConnection();
        //set up query string
        this.teacherQuery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE type=2";
        try {
            //prepare statement
            PreparedStatement teacherState = con.prepareStatement(teacherQuery);
            //execute query
            ResultSet teachResult = teacherState.executeQuery();
            //clear previous items to avoid duplicates.
            jComboBox_teachers.removeAllItems();
            //create counter variable to get different teachers in RS
            int i = 0;
            //while loop
            while(teachResult.next()){
                //get username then add it to position i at combobox
                String tempOption = teachResult.getString("username");
                System.out.println(tempOption);
                jComboBox_teachers.addItem(tempOption); //thanks mcalpine
                //increment i
                i++;
                
                
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FeedbackForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Comment: `executeUpdate(DB.java:895)` - looks like some other code

Comment: @ScaryWombat this seems to be library code, i.e. class `org.sqlite.core.DB`.

Comment: @Dogwolf12 what makes you think the connection is closed? I don't see you closing it anywhere not are you using the auto-close functionality (i.e. try-with-resources).

Comment: @Thomas Too lazy to check, but surprised if `PreparedStatement ::executeQuery` calls `executeUpdate`

Comment: @ScaryWombat ah, that's what you were getting at. Yeah, that seems to be called by some other code - I suspect that's just where the blocked connection manifests itself. The cause might still be in the snippet the OP posted - e.g. if the form somewhere calls `executeUpdate()` and tries to open a new connection.

Answer (score -1):

Found the bug! I needed to make a close-if feature on my Connection class.
Here's the code, should anyone want it:

```
public class DBConnection{
    public static Connection con = null;
    public static Connection getConnection(){
        //initialise connection
        
        try{
            //creates valid url to access DB with
            String url = "jdbc:sqlite:" + System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/TeacherReviewIA.DB";
            
            if(con == null){
                con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            }else{
                con.close();
                con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url);        
            }
            
            //as a debug measure and to show connection given
            System.out.println(con);
        }
        catch(SQLException ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex,"WARNING",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            
        }      
        //allows code that called method to use connection given
        return con;        
    }
}
```

Comment: `public static Connection con = null;` - why have it as `static` ?

Comment: Why are you closing and reopening the connection in the else-block? Why not reuse the connection if `isClosed()` returns false?